# I want to receive realtime notifications for my workday

Tags: notifications, real-time-updates, workday-api

We are working on a use-case where in we need to get real time updates from Workday systems for the events occurring in Workday Systems.

I tried to understand the given documentation but I was not able to understand. I want to get the notifications at an http end point. Please help me get started with the notifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this via Integration Subscriptions and the Notification web service.

Take a look at Workday's documentation on Workday's internal community on how to set this up. A good search phrase would be "Integration Subscription". Essentially, you can subscribe an integration to business processes, and then trigger the integration to kick off and send a notification to an external endpoint.

I've created a contributed solution on Workday Community with more detailed instructions: https://community.workday.com/node/571590

Comment: Can you please suggest some external resources for this than the workday community only. @Erik

Comment: Workday is not open source, so there are not many external resources to leverage. If you are interested in receiving notifications to an HTTP endpoint, then you can set up custom delivery service that sends the payload to an endpoint. Otherwise, you'll need to set up a SOAP endpoint (or an HTTP endpoint that manually parses the soap envelope) to receive the notification. I can update my answer later this week with a more thorough tutorial.

Comment: @ImtiazHussain I've included a link to my own contributed solution on Community that should provide an in-depth guide on how to do this on your own. Good luck, and feel free to reach out with any question on community or here!